# Where did the numbers "802.11" in the wireless network standards come from?

Tags: 802.11

I understand what the 802.11 specifications are, but what is the significance of those numbers?

Comment: [IEEE 802 refers to a family of IEEE standards dealing with local area networks and metropolitan area networks... The number 802 was simply the next free number IEEE could assign, though “802” is sometimes associated with the date the first meeting was held — February 1980.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the IEEE standard identifier. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802